# Displaying a new line on the prompt

Tags: bash, scripts

I wish to add a new line on every prompt. Instead of the cursor showing on the line as 
`name@machine:~$ _`,

I want it to be on the next line, like as:

```
name@machine:~$
_
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

- Open the file `~/.bashrc` (or `/etc/bash.bashrc` if it should work globally for all users).
- Locate the variable called `PS1`.
- Simply put an `\n` at the end of the value of the `PS1` variable.

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to add PS1="$PS1\n" to the bottom of your ~/.bashrc file.

Comment: Guess that's easier to maintain - why don't make it a new answer? :)

Comment: yeah, I did that. there were too many lines to append a \n to, So i created a new variable.

Answer (score 22):

## I prefer using a custom `.bashrc` file

First, append the following lines to your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
##
## INCLUDE CUSTOM `.bashrc` CODE
##
if [ -f ~/.bashrc_custom ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc_custom
fi
```

Create the custom file:

```
touch ~/.bashrc_custom`
```

Finally open it and put the following lines into:

```
# File: $HOME/.bashrc_custom
# THIS FILE IS A USER-CUSTOM BASHRC FILE TO KEEP CLEAN THE DEFAULT ~/.barshrc FILE.
# PUT THERE ANY CUSTOM CODE MANUALLY ADDED BY YOU


# Add a new line at the end of the command prompt
#PS1=${PS1}\\n
PS1=${PS1%?}
PS1=${PS1%?}\n'$ '
```

The next opened shell session will looks like following:

```
user@host:~
$ <your-next-command-will-be-rendered-here>
```

Comment: Why do  you recommend using custom .bashrc file? Isn't exactly why .bashrc in your home directory exists? I understand that you can use and modify default generated .bashrc, but than when you want to use .bashrc on other OSes you can't because you depend on default .bashrc file and if it's not the same it can behave differently.

Comment: Hang on, now, are you recommending against having indirect indirection?

Answer (score 6):

This was painful, but in the end, due to a complicated custom PS1 setup with custom colors, this is the only thing that worked for me:

```
new_line() {
    printf "\n$ "
}
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[01;31m\]$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\]$(new_line)'
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w$(parse_git_branch)$(new_line)'
fi
```

Comment: Great solution. I kindly suggest other new viewers for this solution to view the current `PS` value by using `echo $PS1`. It will have a lot of hints and we can work on top of it especially about the color if you already configured one so.